# Attribute error queryset.filter() django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, mongoengine

So I got a method in views.py that checks if a certain product is saved in the session variables. If this is the case then it will look up the ID of the product in mongodb in order to filter a queryset on a few attributes of this product. I have the following code:

```
def moederbordenComp(request,objectlijst):
    objectlijst_filtered = objectlijst

    if "processorenid" in request.session:
        processor= Processoren.objects.get(id=request.session["processorenid"])
        objectlijst_filtered = objectlijst.filter(Socket__icontains=processor.Socket)

    if "behuizingenid" in request.session:
        behuizing = Behuizingen.objects.get(id=request.session["behuizingenid"])
        objectlijst_filtered = objectlijst.filter(Form_Factor__icontains=behuizing.Form_Factor)

    if "geheugenid" in request.session:
        geheugen = Geheugen.objects.get(id=request.session["geheugenid"])
        objectlijst_filtered = objectlijst.filter(Geheugentype__icontains=geheugen.Geheugentype)
        objectlijst_filtered = objectlijst.filter(Geheugentype__icontains=geheugen.Aantal)

    if "hardeid" in request.session:
        harde = Harde.objects.get(id=request.session["hardeid"])
        objectlijst_filtered = objectlijst.filter(Hardeschijf_bus__icontains=harde.Hardeschijf_bus)

    return objectlijst_filtered
```

So basically. If processorenid exists then filter the queryset called "objectlist" so that only the motherboards remain that contain the processor.Socket.

Now for the real issue:
whenever I remove the objectlijst_filtered and just return the objectlijst (so unfiltered, without doing anything) everything works fine. However if I try to return and then use objectlijst_filtered or even print objectlijst_filtered it raises the following error:`'list' object has no attribute 'join'`

This is the complete error traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/moederborden/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'pcbuilder')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/robin/Work/School/A-Pc/Website/pcbuilder/views.py" in moederborden
  728.     moederbordenlijst = compatibility(request,moederbordenlijst)  
File "/home/robin/Work/School/A-Pc/Website/pcbuilder/compatibility.py" in compatibility
  6.            objectlijst_filtered = moederbordenComp(request,objectlijst)
File "/home/robin/Work/School/A-Pc/Website/pcbuilder/compatibility.py" in moederbordenComp
  34.       print objectlijst_filtered
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py" in __repr__
  58.         self._populate_cache()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py" in _populate_cache
  93.                     self._result_cache.append(self.next())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py" in next
  1137.         raw_doc = self._cursor.next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py" in _cursor
  1182.             self._cursor_obj = self._collection.find(self._query,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py" in _query
  1215.             self._mongo_query = self._query_obj.to_query(self._document)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py" in to_query
  92.         query = query.accept(QueryCompilerVisitor(document))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py" in accept
  157.         return visitor.visit_query(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py" in visit_query
  80.         return transform.query(self.document, **query.query)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/transform.py" in query
  87.                     value = field.prepare_query_value(op, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/fields.py" in prepare_query_value
  106.             value = re.escape(value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py" in escape
  214.     return pattern[:0].join(s)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /moederborden/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've used the filter method in several other parts of the project without any issues so I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you certain that the objectlist value is always a queryset and not a list or set, maybe? You don't maybe run it through a generator or comprehension before passing it to this view, do you?

Comment: Well objectlist does get passed through a few methods before ending up in this view but this is the first time it's used. Basically it contains moederborden.objects where moederborden is of course defined in models.py. Is there any way to check this?

Comment: It might be worth adding a "print type(objectlijst)" at the top of your method to take a quick look at whether you're passing in a list or a queryset. There are several ways a queryset might get changed to a list, but determining whether that has happened will be an important bit of information to gather.

Comment: Alright so `print type(objectlijst)` prints `<class 'mongoengine.queryset.queryset.QuerySet`>` so that seems to be in order. Even if I use `print type(objectlijst_filtered)` the rule below `objectlijst_filtered = objectlijst.filter(Socket__icontains=processor.Socket)` it prints QuerySet. But when I use `print objectlijst_filtered` right after that it instantly gives me the AttributeError even though it's only a rule below the `print type()`.  When I comment out the `objectlijst.filter()` statements everything runs however so it doesn't make any sense.. Thank you so much for your help btw!